# Compiler Error CS0120

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to understand concept "class" and write some easy program. But my function Check() is not correct. Please follow me to the right side..

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Task
    {
        public string RusVer { get; set; } 
        public string Key { get; set; } 
        public string UserVer { get; set; }


        public void Check()
        {
            if (UserVer == Key)
                Console.WriteLine("Good");            
        }
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task p1 = new Task();
        p1.RusVer = "Привет, Мир!";
        p1.Key = "Hello, World!";
        Console.WriteLine(p1.RusVer);
        Console.WriteLine("Translate it: ");
        p1.UserVer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(p1.UserVer);

        Task.Check(); //errorCS0120

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `Check` as if it was static method. It is instance method so it should called `p1.Check()`.

Comment: then p1 - is a instance method? And if i write public static void Check() i must calling Task.Check()?

Comment: Check is an instance method (method called on instance of a type). p1 is an instance.

Answer (score 4):

> [Compiler Error CS0120](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx): An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

So In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must first create an object instance of a class

You need to call it with the help of `Task` class object

```
p1.Check();
```

If you declared `Check()` method as static then you can call it as you are currently doing.

```
 public static void Check()
 {
    if (UserVer == Key)
        Console.WriteLine("Good");            
 }
```